# Reading iOS app requests via ssl proxy

Tags: ios, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to use Charles/burb suite to read request responses sent from an iOS app to a server. The requests are sent via SSL so I've enabled an SSL proxy and installed a cert on my iPhone. This seems to work fine. However the request response and post are still unreadable. Note the response headers are readable just not the actual message.

Is there a way to make the response readable or is this a result of SSL pinning?

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to add the iOS device certificate (which you have done).

2) You need to add locations to the SLL Proxying table.

From the menu: Proxy--->SSL Proxy Settings...--->SSL Proxying

Click Add.

In the Host box, put the site name to translate (use wildcards if needed). Example: *.mysite.com

Leave the Port blank.

Click OK.

Make sure Enable SSL Proxying is checked, and your host filter is also checked.

Click OK.

Restart Charles.